# OpenCart: How to access database

Tags: php, mysql, opencart

I'm trying to access my custom table in the database where I have all my OC tables. I'm basically trying to enter in the product ID to my own custom table after the customer has successfully purchased the product. I'm having trouble translating a normal sql query into the OC syntax:

"$result = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM `" . DB_PREFIX . "table`");"

Let's say I want to "SELECT * FROM test123 WHERE PID = '$x'";
Where "test123" is the name of my custom table.

How can I perform this query in OC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$this->db->query("SELECT * FROM test123 WHERE PID = '" . (int)$x . "'");
```

or

```
$this->db->query("SELECT * FROM test123 WHERE PID = '" . $x . "'");
```

Either of them should work for you.

Usually opencart tables start with a prefix, for example 'oc_'. So all the tables customers, users, etc are named as oc_customers, oc_users, etc. If you have named your table with the same prefix then you can try

```
$this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "test123 WHERE PID = '" . (int)$x . "'");
```

Comment: Its you! Thank you man. How about this statement:
normal SQL:
"INSERT INTO test123(testID, testname, birthday) VALUES ('".$x."',"'.$y.'","'.$date.'"); 
Assuming $x is int, $y is string, and $date is a date in YY-MM-DD format

$this->db->query("INSERT INTO " . DB_PREFIX. "test123 VALUES ('" . (int)$x . "' , '" . (string)$y . "' , '" . (date???)$date . "'");

Comment: $this->db->query("INSERT INTO test123 SET testID = '" . (int)$x . "', testname = '" . $this->db->escape($y) . "', birthday = '" . $this->db->escape($date)  . "'"); You are welcome :)

Comment: MAN!! you are the best.. this worked beautifully! Thank you so much Mehravish!!

Comment: I say man to everyone! haha thank you!!

one more question:

Is there anyway I can add an image to the customer "Downloads" link from their account page?

I'm creating a QR code after they succesfully purchase a product, and I want to add this QR code (png image) to their downloadable page so they can download it!

Comment: You can create a folder in images saying 'qr code' or something, you can save your images there and save path to the table, create the download link on the go whenever the page is displayed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150256/discussion-between-alex-jitromilos-panayi-and-mehravish-temkar).

Comment: hey checkout the chat!